# Got Red Tag warning from gas company for hot water tank (Canada)

Tags: water-heater, safety, diy-vs-pro

Gas company technician asked me to take a look at hot water tank and there he issued me Warning B Red tag and gave me 5 weeks to fix the issue. Issue in related to clearance from combustibles (TSSA code 8.18.t1 t.86) (something about 6 inch clearance from combustibles). Area should in red rectangle is what technician was concerned about. My water heater is old (2010) and was here when I bought the house in 2014. A few contractors I asked to want to sell me new water heater. Is it an easy DIY or should I ask for a contractor to fix it ?

[image: Red rectangle is the area of concern]

[image: Red rectangle is the area of concern]

Comment: Its hard for me to tell is that vent going into the larger pipe, I would be more concerned with a single wall pipe going horizontal with no seal. I would see if the larger pipe T can be lowered and rotated then reduce the height of the stack coming off the water heater.

Comment: How big is your electric service?

Comment: electric service ? This is gas powered water heater. 50 gallon one.

Comment: The warning is because you have very hot exhaust going from the top of the water heater thru a metal pipe (conducts heat) right next to a wood (combustible) stud.  Over time heat build up from the pipe could cause a fire to start.

Comment: Also OMG what lazy **** installed that?  Nice butchering of the wood - too lazy to re-orient the t junction on the main exhaust stack...

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo, Yeah , that was my thought exactly. Even inspection didn't catch it.

Comment: There are insulating blanket materials which could shield the wood, e.g., flexible shield for propane torch close to wood. Ask the inspector if you could slip approved insulating material in between the exhaust flue and the combustible material. You should not need to get a contractor for this job.

Comment: Is that a T fitting into a stack going up going off the top right of the red boxed area?  I hope so...

Answer (score 2):

What size is the vent pipe. Most water heaters use a 3" or 4" flue pipe. If it is larger, and it does look larger than that in the pictures, you could resize it to the correct smaller size, which would yield a little more clearance. Also ask the gas company's inspector if you can replace that single wall pipe with double wall "B" vent of a smaller size (correct size) and also nail  a sheet of 5/8" fire-shield drywall to the butchered wood. Another thought, if the other flue pipe is the one to the left in the top picture, you could cut that pipe, install a pipe flue tee of the correct size and eliminate the flue pipe that is in question. You may need to hire a professional sheet metal person or HVAC company to perform this change since The pipe after the connection point would have to increased slightly.

Comment: All nice suggestions. Thanks. I will update about the size after measuring it.

Comment: These are 3" pipes.